# Loading x,y data into highcharts

Tags: php, javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to load data with x,y pairs.  My PHP backend echoes a string that looks like a nested array, is that what I'm supposed to do?   For example:

> > data1 = [0,0],[0,177],[000,2],[00,4],[1,1],[2.4157,4],[4,1],[5,3],[08,1],[12,1],[12.048,1],[13,1],[55.0541,1],[57.0697,1],[59.000,1],[59.01489482,1],[59.0599,1],[61.03929069,2],[67.0541,1],[69.0332,1],[69.07,1],[70,1],[70.94714329,1],[70.94721663,1],[71.01440325,1],[71.01441409,1],[71.0144472,1],[72.00979129,1],[72.94398353,1],[73.0892000,1],[74.00743457,1],[74.00757108,1],[74.00758939,1],[75,2],[78.9590021,1],[78.95906314,1],[79.054,1],[79.9563,1],[79.96,3],[80.05989973,2],[81.0698,1],[083,2],[83.0491,1],[85.029,1],[86.0237,3],[86.096700,1],[87.00826664,1],[87.00831488,1],[88.0393,1],[88.03948568,1],[88.03949825,1],[88.50764976,4],[91.01570162,2],[91.0542,1],[92.051,1],[92.9270,1],[93.0696,1],[94.9241,1],[95.0853,1],[96.9211,1],[96.9595542,1],[96.96,2],[96.96830364,1];

(Highchart stuff...)

> > series: [{
> >                     name: 'Title1', //php array
> >                     data: [data1] //100's of arrays of point coords
> >                 },{
> >                     name: 'Title2', //php array
> >                     data: data2
> >                 }]

Comment: Almost. You need to have that list wrapped in `[]` as well. Such that it looks like `data1 = [[0,0],[0,177],[000,2],[00,4],[1,1],[2.4157,4],...]`. I am not sure what '000' means so that part is up to you to fix or not.

Comment: Thanks guys, I just needed to use array_map to floats, and then json_encode on the backend, to JSON.parse(data) on the front.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse your data to numbers, because Highcharts don't reconigse strings.

Take look at artcile abour preprocessing data: http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocessing